# C++ Overloaded methods with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, overriding

I have one overloaded function with pointers:

```
void ImageFilter::applyChanges(int ***pixels)
void ImageFilter::applyChanges(int **pixels)
```

I've made a little test to check if compiler knows when to use one or other and it knows.

My question is, how is it possible that the compiler know how to difference between these functions?

Comment: Well, a `int***` and a `int**` are different types.

Comment: But there are just memory addresses, am i wrong?

Comment: Compiler sees them as types, not raw memory addresses

Comment: Sure they both represent an address but the type the address represents is different.  You overload by the type, not the value.

Comment: Oks, something new i learned! Ty so much!

Comment: `char *` and `double *` are just addresses as well :)

Comment: By the same logic `float` and `int` couldn't be distinguished, since they're both 32-bit binary values (on platform X).